# chrome extension : Cancel the download but display the content in a dialog

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to build a chrome extension which will suppress the default behavior of downloading the content and in place of that my extension will display the same content in a dialog.

I have successfully implemented the part of displaying the content in a dialog but my file is still getting downlooaded. I tried adding `cancel: true` in my background script but then everything gets blocked and my content script(log.js) doesn't get executed.

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "description": "Test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": ["background", "tabs", "activeTab", "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "<all_urls>"],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": ["log.js"],
      "all_frames": false
    }
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  }  
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(info) {
    if (info.url && info.url.indexOf('my-url') != -1) {
      // alert(JSON.stringify(info));
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(info.tabId, info, {frameId: info.frameId});
      return {
        cancel: true
      } // cancel the page
    }
  },
  {
    urls: ["<all_urls>"],
    types: ["main_frame"]
  },
  ["blocking"]
);
```

**log.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
      if (request.url && request.url.indexOf('my-url') !== -1) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4) {
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
                const dialog = document.createElement('dialog');
                dialog.textContent = xhr.responseText;
                document.body.appendChild(dialog);
                dialog.showModal();
            }
        };
        xhr.open("GET", request.url);
        xhr.send();
        return true;
      }
    }
);
```

So, how can I achieve this requirement of blocking the download & displaying the content simultaneously.

Comment: Most likely the download uses a different type, not `main_frame`. Add a listener without specifying `types` and inspect the request's `type` property.

Comment: Well your question doesn't make sense. If you don't download a file how do you display it's content? What you are trying can't be be done as far as I know. What you can try instead is maybe trying to generate a preview of the file on a remote server and show that instead of the actual file. But this will require a remote server.